# How to add a validation for a select box such that there shouldn't be same values for more than one select box

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am repeating material angular select box based on the array that I receive from the server :

```
<div *ngFor="let routeval of routemodeArray;let i=index"  layout-gt-xs="row">
<div>
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Select Route" [(ngModel)]="routeval.routeId" name="routeName{{i}}" (change)="routeCheck(routeval.routeId, i, $event)" required >
     <mat-option [value]="null">Select Route</mat-option>
     <mat-option [value]="route.id" *ngFor="let route of getallRoute" [disabled]="routecheckValue == false">{{route.destination}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   <mat-error *ngIf="routeval.routeId == null">This field is required</mat-error>

 </mat-form-field>
```

```
</div>
```

This is the function that gets executed when select box is changed

```js
routecheck(routeval, position, eventData: MatSelectChange){
   console.log(routeval);
   console.log('Route check val');
   console.log(this.routecheckValue);
   console.log(eventData);
   for (let i=0;i<this.routemodeArray.length;i++){
     if (position!=i){
       if(this.routemodeArray[i].routeId == routeval){
         this.routecheckValue = false;
         console.log(this.routecheckValue);
         console.log(this.routemodeArray[i].routeId);
       }
       else{
         this.routecheckValue = true;
       }
     }

   }

 }
```

I'll get more than one select box with with multiple options, these options will be the same in all the select boxes

Now when I select an option in a select box this option should be disabled in all the other select boxes

I'm not able to get an idea how to disable them, as the select boxes and the mat-options inside them are also repeated

Note: I can't use jQuery as I was not allowed to use in m project. Hence it should be done in angular along with typescript.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post the component file as well.

Comment: sure will update  it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybpu2l-cstbtj) is a complete example that behaves as required, simply by keeping track of what selectors have been accessed so far, and what options they are currently displaying.

Comment: Thank you, will check it and let u know :)

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer has been helpful, please mark it as accepted so that other people will be able to see it in the future :)

Comment: ty so much been working on this issue for long time. Your answer solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I select an option in a select box this option should be
>   disabled in all the other select boxes

**UPDATED:**
Something lile this [CODE EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybpu2l-dtsxdh)

Comment: If you select pizza in the second form, you can select pizza again in the third one

Comment: @bugs, realized as I understood 